# Alternative to jQuery mobile / Switch + Toggle btn

Tags: javascript, mobile

I wish to not USE jQuery mobile; I kinda can't stand it.

But I need to create a a mobile friendly; mobile first, simple Switch toggle button.

[image]

Nothing fancy just like the above; I'd likely go in and just add my green.

Any good alternatives for mobile? jQuery latest wont work; unfortunately, and I really don't want to work with crazy weird API. Ideally just plain JS.

Comment: u mean a css switch..u can try this..http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote small plan js switch .. in case you want custom css and require to handle event on toggle.. hope its help

```
   onload = function() {  
   document.getElementById("switch").addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
   };
   function toggle()
   {      
      var sw = document.getElementById("switch");
      var v =  sw.style.cssFloat;
     if( v=='right')
        sw.style.cssFloat ="left";
      else 
        sw.style.cssFloat = "right";  
   }
```

[JS Switch](http://jsfiddle.net/MnNpy/5/)

Answer (score 0):

There is pure Css solutions for your question..This [css toggle switch](http://proto.io/freebies/onoff) uses checkbox for keeping the toggle condition. On if checked and off condition if not checked.

If you do not want to use a checkbox and interested in multiple toggle conditions like tab and other flips.Use this switch. Although I m not sure if this will go fine in mobile devices.

[Switch without checkbox +toggle btn](http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/)